# How to call more times my inner setInterval() function inside a loop? (specific problem)

Tags: javascript, loops, canvas, setinterval

I'm struggling with a function that I call in setInterval. In particular, I would like to recall my render function which draw different lines starting from different points (given a set of values in an array) but cause I iterate this values into a loop it seems like I can start the first setInterval when i=0, but then I cannot stop it and then restart it when i=1 ecc... How can I do to solve this problem?

```
 var degree= [2,0,3,1];
function choose_velocity(degree) {
  let v0; // please give a better name
  for(let i = 0;i < degree.length; i++) {
    var difference = Math.abs(degree[i+1] - degree[i]);
    if (difference === 1) { // always use triple equal (it will compare the type and the value as well
      v0 = 25;
    }
    if (difference === 2) {
      v0 = 36;
    }
    if (difference === 3) {
      v0 = 44;
    }
    if (difference === 4) {
      v0 = 51;
    }
    if (difference === 5) {
      v0 = 57;
    }
    if (difference === 6) {
      v0 = 62;
    }

    if (degree[i+1] - degree[i] < 0) {
      invert_sign = true; // try to use camelCase convention in Javascript
    }

    StartInterval(0.2); // don't name your function with Pascal convention unless you're creating a Constructor function
    console.log("entro convelocità", v0);
  }
}

function StartInterval(frequency) {
  var clear = setInterval(function() {
  render( t += 0.03, clear, invert_sign);
  }, frequency);
}
```

[Codepen code here](https://codepen.io/DvDream/pen/vvmBdo)

I've looked for solution given in the past here but I couldn't solve my problem so please be patient for this..
Thank you in advance anyway! :)

Comment: Hi Davide, I've put your question under review as it requires editing, since the issue is clear--StartInterval does not fire up a second time--but the title and description are hard to read at best.

A few things to try: I would place the setInterval call in your main loop and move all the "choose velocity" logic inside your render function.

Also keep the limitations in mind, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval.

Comment: Since you are dealing with a graphic animation, the solution is to simply **stop using setInterval**. You do not speed up an animation by calling its render at higher frequency, you do it by increasing a *speed* variable, which will be responsible for the increase of coords variables, but render should always fire at a regular interval (max 60fps or a lower multiple min 15 after the brain has not enough info to make it move). And the best timing function we have to regulate that *render* is [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: If I use requestAnimationFrame will I maintain the first line drawn in the canvas when I call cancelAnimationFrame?

Comment: Moreover, the fact is that I need to increase the t variable in order to apply the projectile motion equations, I don't know how to proceed in this way..